# How to get OneDrive profile detail Using OneDrive API in MAC

Tags: onedrive

I want to use OnedDrive API to get OneDrive type, whether it is Personal or Bussiness.I know cid of Onedrive. How can i get this from commandline. Is there any possibility. I tried http, where we can get info by requesting.

Comment: Do you have a way of obtaining an OAuth token for making the call?

Comment: With http, i just logined with one drive credentials for auth,  But i want a way that can be accomplished from commandline